# Do tax preparers have to report findings of illegal activities to any IRS?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, law, state-income-tax

Do tax preparers have to report findings/suspicions of illegal activities —e.g. failure to file for multiple years— of clients or even *potential* clients (seeking advice) to either Federal and/or any State IRS?

Answer (score 5):

The communication [between you and your CPA](http://www.aicpa.org/publications/taxadviser/2013/october/pages/tpp_oct2013-story-03.aspx) (and EA, as it is also a Federally authorized practitioner) is only privileged in non-criminal matters. If you suspect that you may face a criminal prosecution - you can only discuss it with an **attorney**. If a tax advice is need - the *attorney* will hire the tax adviser, not you. All your communication will flow through the attorney to remain privileged ([Kovel doctrine](http://presnellonprivileges.com/tag/kovel-doctrine/)).

For non-criminal matters, CPA cannot and shouldn't disclose to the IRS whatever you have not authorized her to. They may do that anonymously, as the other answer suggest, but if you find out that they were the ones to provide the IRS with the information, you can have them disciplined (and very likely get their license canceled). The IRS cannot subpoena privileged information ([IRC Sec. 7525](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/7525)).

Non-enrolled preparers (i.e.: those who are not CPAs, attorneys or EAs) provide no privilege and can provide to the IRS any information either by their own will or by demand from the IRS.

Comment: As I understand it, not filing Federally is technically a crime (misdemeanor I think). So in a scenario where one went to an authorized Preparer and, in the process of either advice or gathering together records for subsequent filing, revealed the fact of having not filed for multiple years but then decided not to engage Preparer any further... would they still be able (or be required) to pass that non-filing info on to Fed/State IRS?

Comment: @user43431 no. Criminal matter is a matter where the governments brings a legal action against you in court. The government can also bring civil action against you in court, but criminal persecution can **only** be done by the government. For not filing you will be charged penalty, but you will not be put on trial.